# execute a command for each line of stdin immediately?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, xargs, gnu-parallel

How do I execute a command for each line of `stdin` immediately?

**Example**:

```
(echo abc; sleep 10; echo def;) | ???
```

The `xargs` tool does not do the job because it *blocks* until it sees all the data (waits for stdout to close). Yet I have to execute commands immediately as new lines become available.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe might be interesting to read.

Comment: @Hennes Thanks. Unfortunately though, it does not help. The problem is not in the pipe, but in the way how `xargs` works (it waits/blocks until it sees all the input).

Comment: So, do not use xargs. Pass unbuffered output though a pipe and on the other end of the pipe use a shell script to read lines until EOF.

Comment: @Hennes I wrote an example answer to understand the idea behind your comments.

Comment: "The `xargs` tool does not do the job because it blocks […]" – It depends on options in use (e.g. try `xargs -L 1`).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski According to `man xargs`, the `-L` flag sets the maximum lines to be processed. This is very different from processing an infinite amount of lines, but immediately as they come available.

Comment: At most *n* nonblank input lines *per command line*, not in total. `(echo abc; sleep 10; echo def;) | xargs -L 1 echo input:`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the comment, I can confirm it works!

Answer (score 7):

Use a shell script:

```bash
long_running_command | while read -r LINE; do
  echo "line is: $LINE"
  command_to_execute "$LINE"
done
```

In contrast to `parallel`, this doesn't have an overhead of ~ 150 milliseconds + 3..7 milliseconds per line. It also works for executing multi-line bash commands, re-using functions or variables.

The idea is based on the [comment by @Hennes](https://superuser.com/questions/1016686/execute-a-command-for-each-line-of-stdin-immediately/1016708#comment1410867_1016686), finished and written down as an answer. Kudos to him/her!

Comment: The 150 ms is for startup - not per line. The overhead per line is in the order of 3-7 ms.

Comment: @OleTange indeed. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU Parallel:

```bsh
(echo abc; sleep 10; echo def;sleep 10; echo def;)|parallel -uj1
```

`-u` is needed to get the output immediately. Without, the command will run, but output will only be printed later.

`-j1` forces running a single jobslot. Leaving it out will make GNU Parallel read *n* jobs before starting, where *n* = number of cores.

Comment: Whoa, that did the trick! I tried `parallel -u echo`, but, as you said, `-j1` was necessary.